# stored procedure performance issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have billing app which has some report generation feature. after running 6-7 months i am facing wired problem. i sql statement runs perfectly (4 sec to execute) in management studio editor, but when i put same query to SP it takes (1 min 9 sec to execute same query). table has 150K rows. below is the query i am using in SP. My app shows **Timeout expired** exception message. I tried setting timeout in connection string to 180 secs. (for temp. solution) but no positive result.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_GetShiftEndReport](
@BillDate varchar(10),
@JobShift int,
@MonthStartDate varchar(10), 
@MonthEndDate varchar(10)
)
AS
--begin tran
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT        Products.pCode AS ProductCode, MIN(Products.pName) AS ProductName, MIN(Products.pSize) AS ItemSize, MIN(I.gName) AS GroupName, Sales_Trans.Price, 
SUM(Sales_Trans.Sales_Qty) AS SalesQty, SUM(Sales_Trans.Sales_Value) AS SalesValue, SUM(Sales_Trans.Break_Qty) AS BreakQty, 
SUM(Sales_Trans.Break_Value) AS BreakValue, SUM(Sales_Trans.Return_Qty) AS ReturnQty, SUM(Sales_Trans.Return_Value) AS ReturnValue, 
MIN(Products.CloseStock) AS Stock, MIN(Products.pGroup) AS GroupCode, 
dbo.GetCummulativeSales(@MonthStartDate, @MonthEndDate, Products.pCode) AS CummSales

FROM            Products INNER JOIN
(SELECT        SalesLog_1.ProductCode, SalesLog_1.Price, SalesLog_1.Quantity AS Sales_Qty, SalesLog_1.Price * SalesLog_1.Quantity AS Sales_Value, 
0 AS Break_Qty, 0 AS Break_Value, 0 AS Return_Qty, 0 AS Return_Value
FROM            SalesLog AS SalesLog_1 INNER JOIN
Sales ON SalesLog_1.MemoNo = Sales.MemoNo
WHERE        (SalesLog_1.BillDate = @BillDate) AND (Sales.JobShift = @JobShift)
UNION ALL
SELECT        ProductCode, Price, 0 AS Sales_Qty, 0 AS Sales_Value, 0 AS Break_Qty, 0 AS Break_Value, Quantity AS Return_Qty, 
Price * Quantity AS Return_Value
FROM            SalesReturn
WHERE        (BillDate = @BillDate) AND (JobShift = @JobShift)
UNION ALL
SELECT        ProductCode, Price, 0 AS Sales_Qty, 0 AS Sales_Value, Quantity AS Break_Qty, Price * Quantity AS Break_Value, 0 AS Return_Qty, 
0 AS Return_Value
FROM            Breakages
WHERE        (BillDate = @BillDate) AND (JobShift = @JobShift)) AS Sales_Trans ON Products.pCode = Sales_Trans.ProductCode INNER JOIN
ItemGroup AS I ON I.gCode = Products.pGroup
GROUP BY Products.pCode, Sales_Trans.Price
ORDER BY GroupCode, ItemSize DESC;
```

can any one suggest me what to do now. i don't think its query problem may no. of rows.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing same values for the parameters in the SP as in the query (when you didn't use the SP)?

Comment: yes I copied value from SP to the query

Comment: Sorry to sound nagging...however, there are 3 varchar(date) parameters. have you made sure you are passing appropriate (and expected) values for each of them and the values are not getting exchanged between those parameters when you used the SP? Sorry, just checking..

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that the sql is exactly the same and that the params are the same then you could be experiencing a parameter sniffing problem .

It's a pretty uncommon problem. I've only had it happen to me once and since then I've always coded away the problem.

Start here for a quick overview of the problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/31/565991.aspx

http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/17/sql-parameter-sniffing-and-what-to-do-about-it/

try declaring some local variables inside the sp and allocate the vales of the parameters to them. The use the local variables in place of the params.

It's a *feature* not a bug but it makes you go @"$@

Comment: +1 - "try declaring some local variables inside the sp" - This is probably the number one cause of badly performing procs that are otherwise designed correctly in my experience. Widely varying result row counts and inappropriate execution plans. Local variables is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

My friend helped me to solve this problem it was index who was culprit, he created new index and now thing is smooth as butter.

thanks to all SO members, have a great life.

Comment: Creating a new index will force the procedure to be recompiled so if the problem is paramter sniffing you may just have dropped the bad plan from the cache and the problem will recur.

Comment: thanks @martin i will check this and will post the update. thanks for suggestion..

Comment: @martin you were right, it is parameter sniffing problem. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the procedure and then creating it again with the `WITH RECOMPILE` option. This forces SQLServer to not cache the procedure's query plan. As a rule that's a bad thing (because caching the plan saves time, and is one of the main reasons stored procedures tend to be more performant than the equivalent SQL statements), but in some cases that query plan isn't appropriate for all values, and hence causes problems.